# How to add script to Django app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, import

I'm just beginning to learn Django/Python. I created a project called reddit_project with an app called scraper. I'm trying to use my model Link that is in my models.py so that I can create records based on the JSON I am scraping in web_crawler.py. However, Django keeps telling me that the the module scraper doesnt exist when I try to run web_crawler.py in my terminal. How do I properly import the Link class so that it can be used within web_crawler.py?

scraper/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Link(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  subreddit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  upvotes = models.IntegerField()
  downvotes = models.IntegerField()
  posted_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

web_crawler.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scraper.models import Link

website_url = 'http://reddit.com/.json'
response = requests.get(website_url)
reddit_json = response.json()
print(reddit_json)
```

Tree:

```
.
|______init__.py
|______pycache__
| |______init__.cpython-34.pyc
| |____admin.cpython-34.pyc
| |____models.cpython-34.pyc
|____admin.py
|____models.py
|____models.pyc
|____tests.py
|____views.py
|____web_crawler.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Django shell to run scripts within a Django project. You can start the shell by typing:

```
python manage.py shell
```

at the OS command prompt while you are in your project root. You can just import web_crawler.py since you don't have a main method:

```
>>> from scraper import web_crawler.py
```

That being said, the better way to run a script that should access to the Django environment would be to write it as a management command. That way, you can run it using

```
python manage.py <mycommand>
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/ for details.

Comment: I'm running python web_crawler.py in the shell like you said and it's returning

`In [4]: python web_crawler.py
  File "<ipython-input-4-c5e04cc5614b>", line 1
    python web_crawler.py
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Did you add scraper to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Comment: I see! Is there a way to use PDB to debug in this shell?

Comment: I haven't tried before but `>>> import pdb` then `>>> pdb.set_trace()` while in the shell might work.

Comment: what if I want to run this script outside of Django shell? Is there a way I can run the script using the Link model? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: Generally you should make such scripts custom management commands. That way you can access to Django environment, your models from a command line script. See my updated answer.